# How can I access a delegated mailbox in Google Inbox?

Tags: google-workspace, inbox-by-gmail

I use Google Apps and my email is configured to use Inbox. My default delivery address is set to `nobody@example.com`, and my primary account `@example.com` has been granted access by delegation. I've successfully used this from the Gmail interface, but I have no idea how to do it from the Inbox UI.

Oddly, using Google to search for this has been significantly difficult, thanks to the generic terms.

Comment: Inbox is still in wide preview, so it wouldn't surprise me if they've not yet implemented delegation. You'll probably have to go back to the original Gmail interface.

Comment: I've actually asked a question along those lines, too: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/85030/how-do-i-switch-back-from-google-inbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of this writing (October 2015) there is no way to access a delegated mailbox from Inbox for Google without switching back to Gmail. Navigate to mail.google.com and use the delegated mailbox from that UI.