# How do I switch back from Google Inbox?

Tags: gmail, inbox-by-gmail

At some point after switching to Inbox for Google I set it as the default that my account sees at mail.google.com. Now, I want to disable it and return to the old Gmail interface, but I can not, for the life of me, find a setting that will allow me to do it.

How do I change my account's mail interface back to the old Gmail one?

If it matters, my account is a Google Apps account, not a Gmail one.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can stop redirecting `www.gmail.com` to `inbox.google.com` through a setting in Inbox as [detailed here](https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/6230358?hl=en).

> 1. Open **Inbox**
> 2. On the top left, go to the **main menu**.
> 3. Scroll to the bottom and choose **Settings**.
> 4. Uncheck the box for **Redirect Gmail to inbox.google.com**

[image]

Comment: Does that work for Google Apps too, or just for regular consumer Gmail?

Comment: Definitely works for free accounts, not sure about Apps for Businesses. I'd assume for Apps for Businesses the setting is either on the user level, or administrator level.

Comment: It worked fine for my free Apps account.

Comment: It also worked for my google apps/domain account

Answer (score 0):

In the left menu you must have the Gmail field near your contact field, click this and you'll return to your old Gmail interface.

[image: Left Menu]

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the settings icon - the circle on the top right of your Gmail page and then select the first option: "display density", and then choose the "compact" option it will very closely resemble your old Gmail version.

Answer (score -1):

If you prefer using Inbox for most occasions but occasionally require access to Gmail (e.g. for setting rules), instead of changing settings as above, you can click the *Google apps* icon at the top-right (looks like a grid) and click *Gmail*.

Comment: I just tested and this doesn't work if you've got the setting "Redirect Gmail to inbox.google.com" checked. Clicking Gmail in the grid redirects to Inbox.

Comment: You're right. I must have had the checkbox disabled when I was testing this.